# Scroll to view buttons where there are a varying number of buttons

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007, word-2003

I have `selected` a Sentence.

1) The sentence can vary.

2) I have `split` each word of the sentence.

The code below creates a list of `Word array` from `Selection`.

```
Sub Seperate_Words()

    Dim WrdArray() As String

    WrdArray() = Split(Selection)

    For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
        strg = strg & vbNewLine & WrdArray(i)
    Next i

    MsgBox strg

End Sub
```

[image]

Now I want to add a `Search button` in front of each word.

In every situation, the length of a sentence would change and Userforms are Pre-specified that's why I can't use them.

Following Image shows how output should be

[image]

Now problem I am facing is adding a scroll bar in frame which dynamically changes if needed.

[image]

Comment: You can use UserForms. Why do you need to create button for every single word? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: You can also make use of controls such as List View.

Comment: @MaciejLos with the help of `search` button I will able to find ticker from another `MS- excel` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a very interesting solution to this:

Create a UserForm (I have named mine "frmSearchForm")

Create a Frame on it (mine is "framTest")

Create a Classmodule and name it "clsUserFormEvents"

Add this Code to it:

```
Public WithEvents mButtonGroup As msforms.CommandButton

Private Sub mButtonGroup_Click()
'This is where you add your routine to do something when the button is pressed
MsgBox mButtonGroup.Caption & " has been pressed" 'Just Example Code
End Sub
```

Then in the ThisDocument Module, add this code:

```
Dim mcolEvents As New Collection

Sub createButtonsOnForm()

Dim Cmd As msforms.CommandButton

'create instance of class
Dim cBtnEvents As clsUserFormEvents

'array for selection
Dim wordArr() As String

'get selection into array
wordArr = Split(Selection, " ")

Dim i As Integer

'counter for the top position of buttons
Dim topcounter As Integer

topcounter = 10

'loop through array
For i = LBound(wordArr) To UBound(wordArr) Step 1

    'create button
    Set Cmd = frmSearchForm.framTest.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Test")

    'Adjust properties of it
    With Cmd
        .Caption = wordArr(i)
        .Left = 100
        .Top = topcounter
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 20
    End With

    'Instantiate Class
    Set cBtnEvents = New clsUserFormEvents

    'Add cmd to event in class
    Set cBtnEvents.mButtonGroup = Cmd

    'Add buttonevent to collection so it won't get deleted in next iteration of the loop
    mcolEvents.Add cBtnEvents

    'increase the top position
    topcounter = topcounter + 25
Next i

'show userform
frmSearchForm.Show
End Sub
```

Then if you run this sub, the selection gets splitted into the array, a button for every element is created(selection part as caption) and if you press the button, the method inside the class gets called, where you can use the `mButtonGroup.Caption` propery to get the value of button.

Example:

I have selected the Words "Test1" and "Test2", now when I run the Sub, the Form opens with 2 Buttons(Test1 and Test2):
[image: ExampleImg]

Comment: I'm gonna try your code and sooner get to you if I will need help

Comment: your answer is perfect but I am working with sentences as you know long sentence will results `button` that are out side the frame. how do I dynamically change the `size` of frame or add scroll bar that can dynamically change using your code

Comment: An option would be to modify the .Left property to increase after like 10 buttons and reset the topcounter, then it creates the buttons in a new column. Then you would have to add the width of a button to the last column and set this value as width for the frame and form

Comment: form values are change by `With` frmSearchForm
        .Width = 200
    `End With` but frame value is not changing  `With` framTest
        .Width = 100
    `End With` error is `424` object require

Comment: I'll take a look at this tomorrow

Comment: its my mistake `With frmSearchForm.framTest
        .Width = 200
    End With` works fine . thanks